# Scipy fsolve diverges towards infinity instead of the solution

Tags: python, math, optimization, scipy

I want to solve this equation: [image]

However, when I try to solve it with scipy fsolve, it converges towards infinity instead of giving me the solution.

The reason why it goes to infinity is that the function tends to 0 when x tends to infinity:

[image]

Here you have the sample code:

```
def f(x, r): return -e ** (-r * x)

def h(r): return 2 * f(4, r) - f(2, r) - f(10, r)

x0 = np.array([1])

print(optimize.fsolve(h, x0))
```

With some other parameters it finds the solution. However, I want the code to work with different parameters, not just the ones in the example. I also want to avoid the zero solution.

Many thanks

Comment: FYI: In the definition of `h`, it looks like you have reversed the arguments `x` and `r` in the calls of `f`.

Comment: Okay, I change it to r. I thought that the function to solve had to depend on x, as in the example I saw. You are right that obviously the variable can have any name.

Comment: What I meant was, you had, for example, `f(4, x)`, but it looks like that should have been `f(x, 4)`.

Comment: Another FYI: Instead of `e ** (-r * x)`, it is better to use the predefined `exp` function, either from `math` or from `numpy`.  E.g. `np.exp(-r*x)`.

Comment: Mathematically, it turns out that it doesn't matter, because in `f`, the roles of `x` and `r` are symmetric.  Your code worked, but the change of names is confusing (at least it is for this reader of your code!).

Comment: I need to solve for r. As it can be seen in h(r), the values of x are given. I need to be able to solve the equation given some sets of them. Many thanks for the piece of advice on exp()!

Comment: I guess I don't understand your notation.  In the example equation, the only variable is `x`.  There is no `r`, so I don't see how you can solve for `r`.  In the code, it looked to me like `r` is the coefficient of `x` in the exponent.

Comment: I agree with Warren that the notation is confusing.  I also suggest making it consistant to help people answer.  The latex expression uses `x` as the variable to find the zero of, while you are using `r` in the `h` function.  Then `x` appears in the `f` function, but is only used to set the coefficients.  But then you use `x0` again for the initial condition.  Nothing is wrong _per se_, just confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you let `t = exp(-2x)` then the equation is just polynomial, so you can solve it with `numpy.roots`

```py
import numpy as np

roots = np.roots([[-1, 0, 0, 2, -1, 0])
solutions = map(lambda x: -log(x)/2, roots)
```

gives you 3 real and 2 complex solutions.

Comment: Very good idea, but Alex says "However, I want the code to work with different parameters, not just the ones in the example."  If the coefficients are not integrally related, this approach won't work.